# Are the following probability set intersections equivalent?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Are the following probabilities of sets equivalent as indicated? I'm having trouble reasoning how De Morgan's and the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle are applied to work them out if they are:

P(T $\cap$ H' $\cap$ E) = P(T $\cap$ E) - P(T $\cap$ H $\cap$ E)

P(T $\cap$ H $\cap$ E') = P(T $\cap$ H) - P(T $\cap$ H $\cap$ E)

Comment: What does P stand for here? Probability? Power set? Other?

Comment: P = Probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need inclusion-exclusion principle, which I assume refers to the fact that

$$A \cap B = \emptyset \implies P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$$

Now note that

$$P(T \cap E) = P(T \cap E \cap [H \cup H'])$$
$$ = P([T \cap E \cap H] \cup [T \cap E \cap H']) = P(T \cap E \cap H) + P(T \cap E \cap H')$$
$$\implies  P(T \cap H' \cap E) = P(T \cap E) - P(T \cap H \cap E)$$

where I used the fact that $H$ and $H'$ are disjoint, so a subset of $H$ is disjoint from a subset of $H'$.

Comment: I understand that H and H' are disjoint and that subsets of disjoint sets are disjoint, but I don't follow how you applied that in the intersection of their union with T $\cap$ E in $P(T \cap E) = P(T \cap E \cap [H \cup H'])$?

Comment: So you have an outer space in which all elements (for which we define the probability function) lie in, let's call it $X$. We then know that $H \cup H' = X$ because if an element is in our space then it is either in $H$ or not in $H$. Thus, we have for any subset $F \subset X$, the following

$$F \cap X = F \qquad F \cup X = X$$

So I applied the fact that $X = H \cup H'$ which lead to 

$$T \cap E = T \cap E \cap X = T \cap E \cap [H \cup H']$$

and then distributed the set intersection from there. Does that make sense?